# Lambda function and Filter - Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got the following code:

```
f = lambda y, z: filter(y, z)
g = lambda x: [x for x in range(int(x**0.5))]

r = f(g, g(11))
```

I was wondering how `r` ended up being `[1,2]`.

I understand why `g(11)` is `[0,1,2]` but I didn't quite catch how the filter function works here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing all necessary replacements, the functions above can be simplified to

```
filter(lambda x: [x for x in range(int(x**0.5))], [0, 1, 2])
```

Now for `x=0`, the list will be empty (since `[x for x in range(int(0**0.5))]` is an empty list due to `range(0)`), and hence will evaluate to `False`, and for `x=1,2` it will evaluate to True since it will be non-empty.

[filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) constructors the iterator based on the elements for which the function returns True,  hence `0` is filtered out of the list and we get `[1,2]` as the output of the filter function